# Primefaces remotecommand only hitting the back end once

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:remoteCommand name="contentSlideDown"
    action="#{genaricBean.createList()}"
    update=":hform:innerPanel :hform:remoteCommands"
    oncomplete="console.log('contentSlideDown log');"/>
```

I am trying to call this remote command from some JavaScript. The first time it is called it works fine, but every time after that it does not call the back end. I can still see "contentSlideDown log" in my log but `createList` never actually gets called. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you see log that means that AJAX request is completed. Show some context how you are using this remote command, and relevant code of your backing bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked for like 4 hours on this and I just figured it out.

When you do not put a "processed" value in primefaces it defaults to @all (for some reason). There was another part of the page that was failing the process and because of that the entire command was failing and swallowing the error, but still doing the oncomplete stuff.

So the fix was adding:

```
    process="@none"
```